# moneyphp library: from RUB to AZN conversion is always return «zero»

Tags: php, currency

I'm use https://github.com/moneyphp/money library.

Here is a simple example:

```
$ISO    = new \Money\Currencies\ISOCurrencies();
$Parser = new \Money\Parser\DecimalMoneyParser($ISO);

$Exchange = new \Money\Exchange\ReversedCurrenciesExchange(new \Money\Exchange\FixedExchange([
        'AZN' => [
                'RUB' => 30.5867
            ],
    ]));

$Converter = new \Money\Converter($ISO, $Exchange);

$RUB = $Parser->parse('1000.10', 'RUB');
$AZN = $Converter->convert($RUB, new \Money\Currency('AZN'));

echo '<pre>
1000.10 RUB = '.$RUB->getAmount().' RUB PARSED
1000.10 RUB = '.$AZN->getAmount().' AZN
</pre>';
```

Will return:

```
1000.10 RUB = 100010 RUB PARSED
1000.10 RUB = 0 AZN
```

Same is `FixedExchange`:

```
$ISO    = new \Money\Currencies\ISOCurrencies();
$Parser = new \Money\Parser\DecimalMoneyParser($ISO);

$Exchange = new \Money\Exchange\FixedExchange([
        'RUB' => [
                'AZN' => 0.03
            ],
    ]);

$Converter = new \Money\Converter($ISO, $Exchange);

$RUB = $Parser->parse('1000.10', 'RUB');
$AZN = $Converter->convert($RUB, new \Money\Currency('AZN'));

echo '<pre>
1000.10 RUB = '.$RUB->getAmount().' RUB PARSED
1000.10 RUB = '.$AZN->getAmount().' AZN
</pre>';
```

Will return:

```
1000.10 RUB = 100010 RUB PARSED
1000.10 RUB = 0 AZN
```

But:

```
$Exchange = new \Money\Exchange\FixedExchange([
        'RUB' => [
                'AZN' => 3.00
            ],
    ]);
```

Will return:

```
1000.10 RUB = 100010 RUB PARSED
1000.10 RUB = 300030 AZN
```

And...:

```
$Exchange = new \Money\Exchange\FixedExchange([
        'RUB' => [
                'AZN' => 3.01
            ],
    ]);
```

Will return:

```
1000.10 RUB = 100010 RUB PARSED
1000.10 RUB = 0 AZN
```

What's wrong? Where is mistake?

Comment: Catch it!
Error in BcMathCalculator.php or BCMath extension of PHP7.

After remove support of BcMathCalculator.php:

`public static function supported()
{
 return FALSE;//extension_loaded('bcmath');
}`

I got a right value:

1000.10 RUB = 100010 RUB PARSED
1000.10 RUB = 3269 AZN